What is the official name for each of the unicode locale identifiers formats?
Unicode locale identifiers can be written in different formats en-us, en_US, and enUS, what is the official name for each of these formats?
After searching, I found that the format en-us is called BCP47 format, but what about the other formats?

This answer is worth reading Parse both en_US and en-US as locale in Java

en-us is a BCP47 language tag, It can have other subtags, script and -t- or -u- extensions, e.g. th-TH-u-ca-buddhist-nu-thai. BCP47 and the -t- and -u- extensions are the used for the Unicode locale identifiers. Microsoft documentation refers to these as Comparative locale IDs.
en_US is a POSIX locale identifier. The format is [language[_territory][.codeset][@modifier]], so a more complex example would be th_TH.UTF-8@calendar=buddhist. More than one modifier can be included, with modifiers separated by semi-colons.
In ICU4C and ICU4J, for instance, you'll find both BCP47 based identifiers and POSIX identifiers used.
I'm not sure if there is a standard using enUS, but I could be wrong. I've usually seen it as a naming convention for a variable for a locale object. You also have Microsft's use of language (territory) strings and numeric locale identifiers, which Microsoft refer to as Windows Language Code Identifiers (LCIDs) or culture identifiers, although modern versions of Windows have adopted BCP 47 based locale identifiers.

en-us is called BCP47 only in the sense that this is the
name of the standard that specifies the naming convention
using tags and subtags.
You will find details in the Wikipedia article
IETF language tag.
To resume, en-us is a language tag, composed of two subtags:

en is the primary language subtag, based on several ISO standards
us is the region subtag which is in this case a country code
(but can also be a geographical region code).

Note that BCP47 is a general format only as regarding the format
of subtags, primary and secondary(ies). It notes the existence
of multiple standards for the subtags, but does not impose any.
It does not dictate upper or lower case or the separator character
(dash and underscore are dominant here).
A developer is free to select subtags from any one of the noted
standards, or from more than one, or be creative.
Whatever he does would be called BCP47 if it adheres to the
described framework.
(I'm not sure how many developers are even aware of the existence
of these standards.)

How does this even answer the question? It doesn't even mention en_US, and enUS and your explanation for en-us makes no sense.

@DavidPostill: Why does it make no sense? A language tag is something that is well-known and BCP47 is the name of the standard that defines the format. BCP47 is the name of en-us in the sense that ANSII is the name of the letter A. What's wrong in clarifying the concepts?

@DavidPostill: Note that there are many sub-standards and not everybody follows blindly the standard, which gives rise to other variants that may (or not) be supported by other standards. See the Wikipedia article for a list of all the possible ISOs from which such subtags may be derived, while operating systems and applications are not obliged to stick to either of them.

Why is this answer referring to the correctness of another answer?

I think its referring to the question going "I found that the format en-us is called BCP47 format"

@Ramhound: It's not - this answer came first, and there's no conflict.
